# Dell Precision 3660 shuting down for overheating

Tags: dell, bios, acpi, temperature

When monitoring the temperature values of my machine, I see that one of them is slowly increasing under heavy load, ultimately triggering an emergency shutdown from `thermald`.

I read the types of thermal sensors from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type` and their corresponding temperatures from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`

However, I didn't find anywhere the definitions of the values returned by `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type`. Some look pretty self-explaining, like `TCPU` for example. But the offending one for me is `AMBF` and I have no idea what it refers to.

Does anyone know what this `AMBF` stands for and/or where to find some documentation about the various types of thermal zones?

**EDIT:**

I did much searches since the issue first occurred and here are my findings:

- I monitored the thermal sensors and made the following chart
  [image: Temperatures in °C while stressing the machine until emergency shutdown]
  One can see that the CPU and memory temperatures are well dealt with (the CPU TCase is 100°C, so never overtaken). However, the `AMBF` one keeps on growing until it reaches it's critical value of 80°C and triggers the emergency shutdown
- Browsing the ACPI table, I finally managed to find that `AMBF` stands for `AMB and Near Fan Temperature (QE3)`
- I've installed a Windows 10 OS for the unique purpose of testing there. And:

  1. The `AMBF` entry isn't showing up in the ACPI table there (as far as I can see)
  2. The issue doesn't materialize on Windows. Running the exact same test doesn't trigger any emergency shutdown
- Dell published recently a critical customer advisory

> (Dell Technologies Internal Reference ID – Dell Technologies ET004676)
>
> This Customer Advisory is to inform you of a recent discovery involving specific Optiplex and Precision systems which may encounter a thermal shutdown from Modern Standby. Dell Technologies is recommending immediate upgrade to the latest BIOS to maintain optimal system performance and to avoid experiencing any issue.

Needless to say I already was on the latest BIOS version. But I suspect this Customer Advisory might explain why the issue doesn't materialize on Windows... So I tried to boot my Linux system while pretending to be a Windows machine from an ACPI standpoint by using `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2019'` on the boot command line. Unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Anyway, I'm still in the same situation, incapable of using the machine for the purpose I bought it. Any further idea very much welcome.

Comment: What did you use to generate that temperature graph?

Comment: I simply created a script that was monitoring the sensors with awk and printed the output in csv format. I then opened the file in Excel and created the graph. Nothing fancy in that. I'm sure I could have scripted it with gnuplot but I'm just too lazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had an answer from Dell support telling me that the `AMBF` sensor could be safely ignored and the critical shutdown at 80°C disabled.

So I've created a `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ThermalConfiguration>
  <Platform>
    <Name>Override AMBF critical trip point</Name>
    <ProductName>*</ProductName>
    <Preference>QUIET</Preference>
    <ThermalZones>
      <ThermalZone>
        <Type>AMBF</Type>
        <TripPoints>
          <TripPoint>
            <Temperature>95050</Temperature>
            <type>critical</type>
          </TripPoint>
          <TripPoint>
            <Temperature>80050</Temperature>
            <type>hot</type>
          </TripPoint>
        </TripPoints>
      </ThermalZone>
    </ThermalZones>
  </Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>
```

Here, I've decided to set a `hot` level at 80°C where it initially was `critical`, and keep a safety net with a `critical` level at 95°C.

I've also installed the latest `thermald` from [Intel's github repo](https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon)

From there, I've re-run my test and here is the graph of the execution:

[image: Temperatures in °C while stressing the machine]

As you can see, all temperatures are still well managed, and `AMBF` can now freely go over 80°C. It stabilizes at about 92°C at full load, and returns slowly to its normal level when the run is over.

The issue is now fixed and my machine fully operational.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, the name of the thermal zones are defined by your hardware.

For instance, the standard zone on an Intel PC Motherboard is named: `x86_pkg_temp`

And the standard zone on a Raspberry Pi is named: `cpu-thermal`

So you probably have to consult the Kernel source code for the drivers/modules needed for your particular hardware to see things like this.

You might have luck installing the `lm-sensors` package, and after that running `sudo sensors-detect`.

When it's done, it will list the kernel modules needed for the detected sensors.

In fact, I just did the above, and look what I found:

```
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
```

I'm pretty certain that the `AMBF` zone refers to the `Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor` - so it's probably the memory that's getting fried in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. Unfortunately, I still see the issue. See the update for more details if you want.

Comment: Yes I just noticed. Sorry to hear that you haven't found a solution yet - but it seems you actually have researched deeper into the issue, which is always good. Good luck! 

Comment: Yeah, I always take advantage of all the issues I face to learn. Here, I'm learning A LOT. And it makes me appreciate that sometimes, ignorance is a bliss ;-)

Comment: FYI, I've managed to fix the issue